# Integer optimization problem with very many constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Let us consider an integer three-dimensional cube $\{0,1,\dots,100\}^3$.
A point $P$ with nonnegative integer coordinates is said to be a radar point
if all the distances (its number equals $101^3$) from $P$ to the points of the cube are different.
For example, $P(100,5100,510100)$ is a radar point.

How to find a radar point of minimal norm?
Here is my unsuccessful trial for a cube  $[0,s]^3$ with $s=2$.

```
s = 2;
a = Subsets[Partition[Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0, s}, {j, 0, s}, {k, 0, s}]], 
3], {2}];
```

We form all the integer points of the cube and the combinations of these by two. Then

```
NMinimize[Flatten[{Norm[{x, y, z}], Table[Norm[{x, y, z} - a[[d, 1]]] != 
 Norm[{x, y, z} - a[[d, 2]]], {d, 1, Dimensions[a][[1]]}], {x, y, 
 z} >= 0, {x, y, z} \[Element] Integers}], {x, y, z}]
```

produces an incorrect result `{0., {x -> 0, y -> 0, z -> 0}}`.

Comment: For the [0, 2]^3 cube I found `{2, 4, 10}`; does it match your expectation ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what: Thank you for your interest to the question and your work. How do you come to it? What are other radar points? Does your approach work for $s=20$? $s=100$?

Comment: `s=2;a=Partition[Flatten[Table[{i,j,k},{i,0,s},{j,0,s},{k,0,s}]],3]; n=10;b=Partition[Flatten[Table[{i,j,k},{i,0,n},{j,0,i},{k,0,j}]],3]; f[p_]:={p,Length[Union[Map[Norm[p-#]&,a]]]}; Cases[Map[f,b],{_,(s+1)^3}]` `b` removes mirror images to speed it up 4x. `Cases` selects only those with `(s+1)^3` different distances. This is brute force enumeration so the time and memory will go up as `s` and `n` go up.

Comment: @user64494 Brute force NMinimization (including removing of duplicates a la @Bill) while thinking about a viable approach. No chance to scale up.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what:  Thank you so much.

Comment: The code `ClearAll[s]; s = 2;
cube = Partition[
   Flatten[Table[{i, j, k}, {i, 0, s}, {j, 0, s}, {k, 0, s}]], 3];NMinimize[
 Flatten[{Norm[{x, y, z}], 
   Dimensions[Map[Norm[{x, y, z} - #] &, cube]][[1]] == (s + 1)^3, {x,
      y, z} >= s, {x, y, z} \[Element] Integers}], {x, y, z}]` also produces an incorrect result `{3.4641,{x->2,y->2,z->2}}`.

Comment: From the documentation I expect this should work `s=2; cube=Partition[Flatten[Table[{i,j,k},{i,0,s},{j,0,s},{k,0,s}]],3]; constraint[x_,y_,z_]:=Length[Union[Map[Norm[{x,y,z}-#]&,cube]]]==(s+1)^3; Minimize[{Norm[{x,y,z}],constraint[x,y,z]},{x,y,z}, PositiveIntegers]` but the constraint is not being enforced and I cannot see why. Changing `PositiveIntegers` to `Integers` doesn't help. Maybe someone better than I can see what I've done wrong. I realize this is a discrete minimization problem and that is exercising different algorithms inside `Minimize`